# Is it possible to convert uploaded & moved file into UploadedFile() object in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have implemented file uploading using HTML5 FILE APIs,though file chunking, so that I could not perform File Validation on the file , If possible than can you help me how to do ? or not than How to convert uploaded file into `UploadedFile()` object , is there nay way  to do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct a new UploadedFile in this way:

`$file = new UploadedFile($path, $originalName);`

Comment: I have already tried but when I call `$file->isValid()`, it returns `false`.

Comment: ok, have you tried to print `$file->getError()` in order to see the error type?